# Android: GridView with cursorAdapter

Tags: android, gridview, adapter, android-cursoradapter

Hello I have an application that use GridView to load the data from the mediastore using CursorAdapter. It loaded and function except the GridView seems to load every single items in the mediastore by calling the newView in the adapter.

In the logcat, the bindView gets called after calling newView. It works fine when I scrolling the grid where only bindView got called.

It looks like the newView and bindView get called for every items only when I first apply a adapter on gridView.

This was previous post but couldn't find any answer yet:
[Link to previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18822431/how-does-cursoradapter-work-on-android-in-gridview)

Comment: [check this custom library](http://androidcustomviews.com/portfolio/two-way-gridview/)

Comment: better to use getview instaed of newview

Comment: does that mean i don't implement the newView specified in previous post and implement the getView.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behaviour you described is how **CursorAdapter** is intended to work.

**CursorAdapter** has built-in view-recycling:

1. `newView()` is called if new instance of a view object is needed.
2. `bindView()` is then called after this, `bindView()` receives and a view that was previously returned by `newView()` (not necessarily in the same order). bindView's job is to set the view into the proper state according to the data from your cursor.

Now, when you scroll around, some views get pushed out of the visible area, while new views get dragged into the visible area. The new views need to be instantiated and the state set according to the data from the cursor. This could be done by repeating step 1 & 2.

However, with view recycling the views that get pushed out of the visible area get thrown into a "pool of recycled views", **CursorAdapter** will try to re-use these views and hand it to `bindView()`, thus skipping step 1 (And saving resources).

So why is `newView()` called when you set the adapter ?

Simply because the pool of recycled views is empty, no views have been scrolled out of the visible area yet, thus Cursor Adapter has no choice but call `newView()` to get a new instance of view and then pass it to `bindView()`.

To sum it up:

- `newView()`: creates an instance of view (usually by using layout inflater)
- `bindView()`: sets the state of the view received as a parameter according to your cursor-data (e.g. text, images, buttons etc.)

Hope this clears up some of the confusion.

Comment: Why does the bindView got called for each of the elements in the cursor and not just the visible area of the gridView? I have 140 of images and the bindView got called 140 times as the newView is. Does that mean I shouldn't use this adapter.

Comment: i just checked your other thread, you didn't set the height and width of your ImageView, depending on your settings of GridView it will stuff all 140 items into the gridview, since it can fit all 0x0pixel views into the visible area.

Comment: Oh I have to check that out..